# How to see the names of Form Control buttons in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel, I am using Form Control Buttons (FCB) to call a User Form.  When I insert the FCB a name for that FCB is created by Excel (for instance Button11) and it asks me to assign a macro to that FCB.  *Is there a project or object explorer that can show me the names of the FCB placed onto the spreadsheet?*  My user form runs a macro based on which application calls it.  I am relatively new to Excel/VBA programming.  THANKS!

Comment: You can link the buttons on the worksheet to a common macro, and inside the macro use `Application.Caller` to get the name of the pressed button.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks!